# How to get selected value of a gridview column which in jquery?

Tags: jquery, gridview, data-binding

I am having gridview bind using Jquery like this with 3 columns..

```
 var text = "<tr><td>" + '<input id="gvChk" class="gvChk" type="checkbox">' 
             + "</td><td>"  + oPorts[i].BookingData
             + "</td><td style='display:none' class='csBookingID'>" 
             + oPorts[i].BookingID + "</td></tr>";
 $('.iframe').contents().find('.gvPorts').append(text)
```

i just want to get value of oPorts[i].BookingID bind to value of checkBox so that when i change checkbox ,i can get values of BookingID

My trial was like this which agve me Undefined value

```
     $('.iframe').contents().find('.gvPorts input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
     var BookingID = $('.iframe').contents().find('.gvPorts td csBookingID').val();
     alert(BookingID);                  
                        if (this.checked)

                            alert('checked');
                        else
                            alert('not checked');
                    });
```

In general how can i get values of GridView which is bind by Jquery..

How can i do it in my scenario.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i get from you is that you have table first column is checkbox and the second column contain some data you 'll use later based on the change of the checkbox and you don't want to display this second column..

So rather than using another column simply put your data (BookingId) just as another attribute in the checkbox.

```
var text = "<tr><td>" + "<input id='gvChk' class='gvChk' type='checkbox' bookingId='"+oPorts[i].BookingID+"'>"
             + "</td><td>"  + oPorts[i].BookingData
             + "</td>" 
             + "</tr>";
 $('.iframe').contents().find('.gvPorts').append(text);
```

then to get the value use [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$('.iframe').contents().find('.gvPorts input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
var BookingID = $(this).attr('bookingId');
alert(BookingID);                  
if (this.checked)
    alert('checked');
else
    alert('not checked');
});
```

Comment: Eeven tough we use hidden filed, how to fetch those values ?

Comment: How to take hidden filed as coulmn and bind values to hidden field here?

Comment: Here iam getting BookingID Undefined..., NOT getting value

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want value of `BookingID`

```
$('.iframe').contents().find('.gvPorts input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
     var BookingID = $(this).find('td csBookingID').val();
     alert(BookingID);                  
                        if (this.checked)

                            alert('checked');
                        else
                            alert('not checked');
                    });
```